# Do I need to always use a setter since contracts are essentially permanent?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

So, from what I understand, it's a good idea to use temporary contracts and redeploy when a change is necessary. Let's assume that I controlled a smart lightbulb with the following code.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Lightbulb {
  enum LightState { off, on }
  address public owner;
  LightState light;
  LightState constant defaultChoice = LightState.off;
  uint public cost = 1 ether;

constructor () public {
    owner = msg.sender;
 }


modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
 }

function turnOn() public payable {
    require(msg.value == cost);
    light = LightState.on;
 }

function turnOff() public {
  light = LightState.off;
 }

function getState() public view returns (LightState) {
  return light;
 }

}
```

Should I just redeploy the contract if I wanted to change the cost? Also,  I could put the cost in a constructor, but if I wanted to change the cost I would still have to redeploy so does that really matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contract deployment is very costly and you typically want to avoid it whenever possible. You would deploy a new contract when business rules change. For a simple state change operation like the one you described, you would want to provider a setter for the cost that uses the `onlyOwner` modifier to restrict access.

Comment: Would it be excessive to have the contract that controls turning the light on and off inherit ownership and change of cost functions from another contract?

Comment: If you have a case for reuse, sure. Other, it’s not really going to matter. The deployed versions will be pretty much identical.

Comment: Ok, I was considering security benefits, but if there are none I’ll avoid it for this example as I build on it. Thanks for the answers.